# Can't add multiple items to tableview from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I have a var favoritesCache, of which the value (type string) changes upon a segue from another VC. This variable is then used to populate an empty array via append.

I am able to get data to appear in the tableview in the first row. But as new data is sent to the second VC, the array and tableview are provided with new data, but the first row is overwritten with new data. This is preventing me from presenting multiple rows of data.

My suspicion is that the array is being dropping the older data when new data is appended. But I'm not sure how to get the array to hold onto all the data.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Second View Controller**

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var favoritesCache = ""

    var receivedData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        receivedData.append(favoritesCache)

    }
}

extension FavoritesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return receivedData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = receivedData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.receivedData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

**First View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    let materialData = [
        "Acetaminohen Powder, Unmilled     43 lbft     0.688794 gcm3",
        "Acetylene Black, 100% Compressed     35 lbft     0.560646 gcm3",
        "Acetylsalicyic Acid     20 lbft     0.320369 gcm3",
        "Acrylamide     34 lbft     0.54463 gcm3",
        "Acrylic Granules, Coarse     40 lbft     0.64 gcm3"
    ]

    var searchMaterial = [String]()
    var searching = false
    var textToBeSent: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print(self.materialData[indexPath.row], "selected!")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let info = segue.destination as! FavoritesViewController 
        info.favoritesCache = textToBeSent //sends table row data to var(favoritesCache) in favoritesVC, info is segue
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Favorite") { (action, indexPath) in

            if self.searching {
                self.textToBeSent = self.searchMaterial[indexPath.row] 
            } else {
                self.textToBeSent = self.materialData[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { (action, indexPath) in
            print("share button tapped")
        }
        share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return [favorite, share]
    } 

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchMaterial.count
        } else {
            return materialData.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        if searching {
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        searchMaterial = materialData.filter {return $0.contains(searchText)}
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension UIViewController { //provides method for hiding the keyboard

    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard(_:)))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)

        if let nav = self.navigationController {
            nav.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the array?

Comment: post second controller where you get data ? are you appending it ? or setting it

Comment: jawadAli, the code above is my second view controller. But I'll post my first view controller for comparison.

Comment: Frankenstein, I'm setting it in the second view controller with var receivedData = [String](). And populating it with receivedData.append(favoritesCache) in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Each time you segue to the second view controller you get a new instance of that view controller, so `receivedData` is an empty array. You need to store your application state in some other data model object that your view controllers can use and pass to each other

Comment: Show us the code where you add/set data to "receivedData". I am assuming you get this data from server or core data?

Comment: receivedData is populated via appending the variable favoritesCache. This variable is populated from string data being sent from the first VC - initiated by a swipe action in a tableview in the first VC

Comment: Paulw11, please excuse my ignorance, I'm extremely new to iOS development. So if I understand you correctly, I should populate an array in a separate swift file and then use that array to populate the table in my second VC?

Comment: I understood that. You said in your question "But as new data is sent to the second VC, the array and tableview are provided with new data, but the first row is overwritten with new data.". I wan't to see the code where you assign this "new data" to "receivedData"

Comment: ibnetariq, I apologize, I don't think I posses the proper vocabulary or understanding to give you the information you're asking. All I can say is the code I've posted is all of my code. I'm using the prepare for segue to pass the data to a variable in the second VC and appending that variable to the array. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain that in any other way.

Comment: No need to apologise. I am going to give it another look. Let's see if I can help you in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213654/discussion-between-ibnetariq-and-sean-patterson).